# Refactoring migrations into a new file without losing Table data Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, migration

I created a table Users and after refactoring our design, we realised more fields were needed in talbe. The table is modified in three different migrattion files and I'd like to refactor it into one file without losing all my data. Any idea how? This are my three migrations:

`

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    drop_table(:users, if_exists: true) # uncomemnt only if you want to reset
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

`

`

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :email, :string
  end
end
```

`

```
class AddStudentToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :student, :boolean
    add_column :users, :landlord, :boolean
  end
end
```

``

I'd like to combine these into one migration like

`

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.boolean :is_student
      t.boolean : is_landlord
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

`

Any idea how to refactor? I get an error when I run this new migration to create new table. Is there a way to create and store old data?

Trying to get new migration that restrctures talbe and saves old data. Trying to make my code look cleaner.

Comment: What’s the purpose of the refactor? Just for cleanliness sake?

Comment: I would agree that you should not refactor migration files. When they are run, their identifier is stored in the schema versions table in the database. Changing migrations therefore would require updating the schema versions table too. Because migrations usually only run once per environment, there is not really a benefit in doing this. Furthermore, I often delete older migration that were run on all environments on a regular basis. There is no point in keeping them, working with the `schema.rb` is much faster and easier.

Comment: As a beginner you want to worry less about making your code look clean and more about it actually *being good*. Prefixing booleans with `is_` and replacing working code uneccissarily with code containing a syntax error is not great. I wouldn't use multiple booleans here - instead use a roles table and set up a one to many assocation. See http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2012/10/10/booleans-are-baaaaaaaaaad/

Comment: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Answer (score 2):

You don't refactor migrations.

> In general, editing existing migrations is not a good idea. You will be creating extra work for yourself and your co-workers and cause major headaches if the existing version of the migration has already been run on production machines. Instead, you should write a new migration that performs the changes you require. Editing a freshly generated migration that has not yet been committed to source control (or, more generally, which has not been propagated beyond your development machine) is relatively harmless.
> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Beyond that its also just a huge waste of time since migrations are simply meant to provide a mechanizm for transforming the data schema in a repeatable way across environments - they are not indended to be long lived in your code base.

In fact as soon as a migration has been run across all environments it should be deleted*. When a new environment is set up it should be done by recreating the schema from `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` - not by running every single migration the project has amassed during its lifetime which is very slow and error prone.

If you ever would need the migration again (which you won't) it will be in your VCS history.

Comment: * "There's a caveat, though. Rake tasks to install migrations from engines are idempotent. Migrations present in the parent application due to a previous installation are skipped, and missing ones are copied with a new leading timestamp. If you deleted old engine migrations and ran the install task again, you'd get new files with new timestamps, and db:migrate would attempt to run them again."